# How can I find what file a value is defined in?

Tags: coq

When I work on a Coq proof I often want to find which file a definition comes from.

E.g. I had a goal which contains `list_norepet (map fst (PTree.elements ta))`, and I wanted to find the file that defined `list_norepet`. Doing `Print list_norepet.` shows lots of helpful information, but not the file name. Is there any way to get Coq to print that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Locate` to get the full module name. Usually this is enough to find the file, but then you can use `Locate File` to try to find it:

```
Locate eq_rect.
(* Constant Coq.Init.Logic.eq_rect *)
Locate File "Init/Logic.v".
(* /Users/tchajed/code/sw/coq-master/theories/Init/Logic.v *)
```

I say "try to find it" because you do need to know the remappings (with `-R`) to be able to translate module paths to file paths - for example, Coq's standard library is in `theories` but is mapped to `Coq`.

Comment: `About eq_rect.` also shows the full module name + some other useful information.

Comment: I feel that `Locate` can indeed improve quite a bit, please file an upstream issue.